# How to set the SQL Query for a Report?

Tags: crystal-reports

Crystal Reports 2011.
Database is MS Access 2003

I have the following tables:

Calendar

has Date entries for the current and next Year, for every Day of the Year, plus some Status Fields marking certain days as "Special" (Joining this table so I have a record for Days with no activity.

```
Staff table
StaffNo
Name
.
.
.

DayResults
Date
StaffNo
Status
.
.
.
```

The DayResults table has one entry per Day and Staff. 
Entries are only made when the staff gets an entry by the Program for Status or other events. Staff that does not log in the system has no entry for this Day.
So, in case of John not showing up on July 2nd, i have no entry for him for this Day. But I need an entry for my report!
I need to create a Report that fetches Data from the  DayResults Table and make calculations on the Parameters here, in order to calculate a Daily as ell as Period Bonus.
The rules for this Bonus require that a Day without activity (i.e. No Show) results in a negative bonus amount.

Therefore I need to have a select statement which creates an entry FOR EACH DAY FOR EACH STAFF.

This should look like this:

```
Date         StaffNo      Name     Status
2016/07/01   1            Jim      1
2016/07/01   2            John     2
2016/07/02   1            Jim      2
2016/07/02   2            John     NULL
```

(John did not show up on 2016/07/02 ...)

```
SELECT Calendar.Date, Staff.StaffNo, Staff.NickName, DayResults.Status
FROM Staff LEFT JOIN (Calendar RIGHT JOIN DayResults ON Calendar.Date = DayResults.Date) ON Staff.StaffNo = DayResults.StaffNo;
```

Unfortunately, no entry here for John on July 2nd?

Any idea how to proceed?

Manfred

Comment: what is the output of this query? `Calendar RIGHT JOIN DayResults ON Calendar.Date = DayResults.Date`

Comment: You mean I should take the second JOIN off?

Comment: No Just I want to know are you getting the expected records for inner query?

Comment: Results are pretty much the same, ... John's still missing on the 2nd, everyone else is there.

Comment: I guess it should be otherway around...first run the query between staff and daily as inner query then link the result with the calender table

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will try this tomorrow and report! Dinner now (I live in Thailand ...)

Comment: No problem try and let me know